# Google chart tools get rid of horizontal spacing

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, google-visualization

I have a histogram that i want to render with `ColumnCharts`, I followed the tutorial and did it and got this as an result:

[image]

Note the spacing at the either end of the graph (particularly the left side as the right side have some columns that's very small)

I tried to use `viewWindow` but it seems to have no particular effect. Here's the code (coffeescript) that's used to draw it. The data has been snipped to save space as they are fairly big

```
    data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      labels, bardata
    ])

    # The labels are ["x", "label for each column" ....]
    # bardata is [number, number, number] (these numbers are the height of the column)


    chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("enrollment-total-chart"))
    chart.draw(data,
      width: 400
      height: 300
      hAxis:
        title: "Number of students"
      vAxis:
        title: "Number of schools"
      viewWindow:
        max: "auto"
        min: 0
      viewWindowMode: "explicit"
      legend: position: "none"
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is likely with your data. For instance, if I make this chart:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
    ['A',  0,   0,   3,   4,   5,   0],
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
      draw(data,
           {width:600, height:400,
            hAxis: {title: "Year"}}
      );
}
```

There is a lot of white space at the left/right of the chart due to the zeroes (my guess is that you have a lot of zeroes in the extremes).

I'm a bit confused also by your data -- you say you have many different rows, but a histogram is just a pair of X Y data, so the use of color (differentiating the series) is a bit different than a standard histogram.

If the above doesn't answer your question, could you please include your data so that we can understand a bit better what you're trying to do (anonymized if necessary).

Comment: The data is pretty big, but you're right: It is due to extremely small data on the right end. Not sure how the left end is like that as I switched displays. I also abused the Google DataTable by using columns instead of rows.

Comment: Is your axis continuous? If not, then you can't set the ViewWindow (or rather can set it, but it won't do anything). If you are using a continuous axis, and it isn't working, then I have no idea why.